# Finding first statistically significant point of s curve (sigmoid function) where slope decreases?

Tags: statistical-significance, bioinformatics

Apologies if my title is awful. I have very little statistics experience so I'm hoping the title makes sense.

Background on what I'm doing:

I'm working on a program that calculates the minimum inhibitory concentration (MIC) and minimum lethal concentration (MLC). A peptide is used at multiple concentrations (i.e. 128, 64, 32, 16, etc) and data is recorded over time based on bacteria growth. At a specific time you take the data for each concentration and end up with an S curve where the first several points will be where concentration of the peptide is the lowest resulting in maximum growth and growth gradually drops as concentration is increased until it flattens out at the highest concentrations.

This link provides a good example of what the data looks like that I'm working with although in the first two plots where they have NIC that's my MIC and where they have MIC is my MLC. Also while this link is an example of what my data looks like they are calculating the MIC and MLC differently than I want to: https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/fitting-bacterial-growth-data-to-determine-the-mic-and-nic/

The professor I'm working on this for wants me to take the first point that shows statistical significance for both my MIC and MLC. So I figure to find the MIC I'll work left to right and find the first point that shows a significant drop and that will be my MIC. Then I'll work right to left and find the last point before a significant increase in growth which will be my MLC.

With almost no statistics background I'm honestly not even sure where to start. I've read about p-tests but not sure exactly how I'm supposed to set up my test. I've read about calculating the standard deviation but I'm not sure what points I would even use to calculate that. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!